# Interpreting p value in SciPy Welch's T-Test

Tags: t-test, python, scipy

Can someone help me understand the meaning of the p-value of the Whelch's T Test in SciPy?

`test = stats.ttest_ind(x, y, equal_var=False)`

gives me

`Ttest_indResult(statistic=5.4320992218489925, pvalue=7.614106565771353e-08)`

But with a statistic of 5.43, shouldn't be a 0.00000... p-value according to the T table instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in fact a pvalue of 0.000000...

That format tells you that the value is 7.614106565771353 times 10^-8, 
So it's 0 point followed by 7 zeros than 7614 ecc..

Comment: thanks! That makes perfect sense, i didn't think about it.

Comment: It is 0 point followed by **seven** zeros and then 7614... Just like $10^{-3}$ is 0,001